# C-source file for /usr/include header (e.g. stdio.h)

Tags: c++, c, gcc, header, include

I would like to try around with openssl and want to therefore alter the source.
I found code that includes `#include <openssl/ec.h>` and obviously uses functions from that header. However I can not find the file ec.c which to my knowledge of C usually is located with the header (at `/usr/include/openssl/ec.h`). Same in the github source of openssl (https://github.com/openssl/openssl), ec.h is located at `openssl-master/include/openssl` but there is no ec.c

So: **Where does gcc look to find the methods defined in ec.h?**

Thank you for answers!

Comment: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/tree/master/crypto/ec

Comment: `.h` and `.c` are usually **not** stored together. Also, the functions are most probably not "defined" but declared in `ec.h`, so please be clear about that. GCC probably doesn't look for the implementation files by itsself at all but assumes you to specify the library manually as with pthread (`-lpthread`).

Comment: In C there is no requirement that every `X.h` file has a corresponding `X.c` file (though often there is). The compiler (linker actually) will look for unresolved symbols in the libraries (shared or static) that is passed to it.

Comment: @kaylum:  Not only shared libraries: static libraries too.

Comment: @MartinBonner Yep agreed, good clarification.

Comment: DimBimJim:  What are you planning to do?  Please don't be offended, but you strike me as fairly new to C programming.  Cryptography is not a particularly good place for a newcomer to start: it's an area where *the* most important requirement is a non-functional one (security) - you can't write tests for "is this secure?"

Comment: @cad However I do not specify a library path for the implementation files, the implementation only includes `#include <openssl/ec.h>` and kind of works out by itself where to find the defintions for the declarations. Now I would like to know where those defintions are, so I can edit them. Thank you for clarifying the defintion/declaration difference, I will remember!

Comment: @Martin Bonner, yes I am not a experienced programmer, however I have to do it for a mandatory university project.

Comment: OK.  If this is an exercise, that's fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand you want to modify the OpenSSL source code. In C programming it is not necessary that all the /h files should have a corresponding .c file.

> There must be one to many mappings between header files and source
>   files. Even though you din't have corresponding ec.c for ec.h file
>   under OpenSSL, the functionalities declared in ec.h might be defined
>   some where else(in any other source file of openSSL or some other
>   dependency). Finally your OpenSSL binaries that is libeay.lib/.so and
>   SSLeay.lib/.so (Considering linux platform) would have the symbols
>   defined for the corresponding function declarations.

I assume you are trying to look into the system installed OpenSSL library where you would find only the header files and the binaries not the source code. You can download the OpenSSL source from the git repository and try to make the changes to the sources and build it.

As told earlier you may have the functions defined some where in source format or binary format so that the final output (binaries) got linked to the definitions.

Comment: Umpfhh, I get it now. So the #include gets the pre compiled binary functions declared in the header. There is no way to refer back to see which source files include a specific header. It only works the other way around. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For large library projects (like openssl) it is normal to put the header files in an `include` directory, and the source files in a separate source directory.  Client applications need the include files and the compiled library - but they *don't* need the library source files.

To answer your question:

https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/apps/ec.c

Also, the functions are *not* **defined** in `ec.h`.  They are **declared** there, and **defined** in the corresponding .c file.  The distinction between declaration and definition is an important one in both C and C++.

Finally, there doesn't *have* to be a single `ec.c` file corresponding to an `ec.h` header.  It's a common convention, but other libraries might be structured so that there was a single header (for ease of use by the user), but a number of separate source files (to help organize the library).  So you might have `ec_core.c`, `ec_sign.c`, `ec_encrypt.c`, `ec_key_exchange.c`.

Comment: Thank you that helps, but still: How does gcc know that the function `foo` declared in ec.h is located in `crypto/ec/ec_core.c` and not in `crypto/ec/ec_sign.c`? Because when I am including the header I am only including `#include <openssl/ec.h>` and no directory where to find the defintions...!?!  Thank you for clarifying the defined/declared difference, I will remember!

Comment: When gcc compiles `ec_core.c` it finds all the functions defined there, and creates `ec_core.o` with the object code for the functions. In the simple case the linker is given all the `.o` files and links them all together.  With something like openssl, the library (?ar?) utility collects the .o files together into a library, and your test program is linked against the library.